# Unable to load dynamic libarary iconv - cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I have recently installed whm/cpanel. I have manually installed iconv via terminal. 
I have also updated the multi .ini file. I am still getting this error on my website.

> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_iconv.dll' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_iconv.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I did enter php_inconv.dll inside the .ini file but even after removing that i am still having the same issue.